# Apostol Calculus volume 1, Archimedes method of finding the area under the curve

Tags: calculus

So I just began reading Apostol's Calculus, and, discouragingly, I've found myself confused by the very first proof.

(Skip to Figure $1.5$)

[image]
[image]
[image]

What I don't get is why the horizontal component of each rectangle is $b/n$ rather than just $b$. I mean, at first I thought that the coefficient of $b$ was $n$ as well, so the distance would be...just $b$, but that turned out to be wrong as when the area of the rectangle is asserted, it is $(b/n)*(kb/n)^2=(b/n)^3*k^2$. I guess I just don't understand what $n$ is. Is $n$ not $k$ in this case? Is $n$ not $1$ in the first rectangle? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, $n$ is the number of rectangles, whereas $k$ is the index of each rectangle. So, if there are $20$ rectangles, and you're calculating the area of the seventh rectangle, then $n = 20$ and $k = 7$.